# Python function such as max() doesn't work in pyspark application

Tags: python, pyspark

Python function max(3,6) works under pyspark shell. But if it is put in an application and submit, it will throw an error:
TypeError: _() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you have an import conflict in your application most likely due to wildcard import from `pyspark.sql.functions`:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.10 (default, Oct 19 2015 18:04:42)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.

In [1]: max(1, 2)
Out[1]: 2

In [2]: from pyspark.sql.functions import max

In [3]: max(1, 2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-bb133f5d83e9> in <module>()
----> 1 max(1, 2)

TypeError: _() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Unless you work in a relatively limited it is best to either perfix:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sqlf

max(1, 2)
## 2

sqlf.max("foo")
## Column<max(foo)>
```

or alias:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max as max_

max(1, 2)
## 2

max_("foo")
## Column<max(foo)>
```

Comment: If you don't import from `pyspark.sql.functions` then as usual. There should be no conflicts. But if it doesn't work please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the response! What you explained makes sense. But how to invoke max() under my own spark context. 
from pyspark.sql.functions import max as max_
if __name__ == "__main__":
  print max(1,2)

It doesn't work for me.

But I have to import pyspark.sql.functions for other purposes.

Comment: I solved the problem by 'import __builtin__'  then  'print __builtin__.max(1,2)'. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3610141 You mean import builtin**s**. I think it worth an answer.

Comment: I just spent a whole day on this. I cant believe this got no upvotes. OMFG! :-)

Answer (score 6):

If you get this error even after verifying that you have NOT used `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`, then try the following:

Use `import builtins as py_builtin`
And then correspondingly call it with the same prefix.
Eg: `py_builtin.max()`

*Adding David Arenburg's and user3610141's comments as an answer, as that is what help me fix my problem in databricks where there was a name collision with min() and max() of pyspark with python built-ins.

Comment: Or, if your more likely use the spark version of max than the builtin, you can do something like this:
from builtins import max as py_max, min as py_min