# Pyspark Error while using Python Functions in UDF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am working in pyspark for a simple data analysis problem. Some of my work is already in Python which I am porting over to pyspark.

While using the following lines of code in Python UDF inside pyspark, I am getting an error, however these lines work perfectly in Python interpreter.

`param = max(val, key=val.count)`

**The error is:** PythonException: 'TypeError: max() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'

I had to use a workaround to get away from this error. Any idea why I am seeing this difference between Python interpreter and UDF?

Python runtime in Spark: 3.8

Comment: which `max()`is it - python or pyspark? what was the workaround?

Comment: this the max function from python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a conflict between python built in max function and pyspark max function.
If I try this:

```
def get_max(val):
    return max(val,key=val.count)
```

The result is fine, because it only recognize and uses the python builtin max function.

But if I add an import for the pyspark max:

```
def get_max(val):
    from pyspark.sql.functions import max
    return max(val,key=val.count)
```

I get the error you mention:

[image: error]

The solution is to import the built-in function and refer to it.

```
def get_max(val):
    from pyspark.sql.functions import max
    import builtins as py_builtin
    return py_builtin.max(val,key=val.count)
```

Which works OK.

The solution is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59394797/21079004

Comment: Many pyspark developers use the alternative too, which is to alias the pyspark sql functions with `from pyspark.sql import functions as F` and then all SQL functions are explicitly invoked with `F.max()` which avoids over-shadowing built-in functions or other variables.